# (ZF) Dedekind infinite + Limit Point Compact ⇒ Separable

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

[If every infinite subset has a limit point in a metric space $X$, then $X$ is separable (in ZF)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180238/if-every-infinite-subset-has-a-limit-point-in-a-metric-space-x-then-x-is-se)

Yesterday, i posted this question and got an answer that 'Limit Point Compact⇒Separable' is unprovable in ZF.

As you can see, the proof in the link is done by the fact that there could be an infinite set which doesn't have a countable subset. I accepted the equivalence as an consequence of AC and continued my study.

However, most of spaces in classical analysis are Dedekind-infinite(i.e. $X≧|\aleph_0|$) as far as i know, and i have no idea how to prove this in ZF.(Since the way of my argument i tried today is exactly the same as the one i tried yesterday, that is, i can't make a countable choice).

I want to prove this if possible, or know whether it is unprovable. Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the same space as JDH suggested, and embed it into $[0,1]$, now add to that the interval $[2,3]$.

This set is Dedekind infinite and limit point compact, but it is not separable for obvious reasons.

---

I couldn't find anywhere a particular account for the exact consistency strength needed for this sort of statement. However if there are no infinite D-finite sets then the assertion "Every infinite set has an accumulation point" is equivalent to that of "Every sequence has a convergent subsequence"

I have a hunch that this too is not enough to prove that $X$ is separable.

Generally speaking, though, there is a plethora of statements about metric spaces and compactness, Lindelof-ness and such, all which are equivalent to countable choice. I would not be surprised if this turns out to be equivalent to the axiom of countable choice as well, but I don't have much time nowadays to sit and tackle this problem on my own.

Comment: Do you have any idea what statement $\psi$ makes '$\psi$+limit point compact ⇒ separable' possible?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it is in fact equivalent to countable choice. If you have Herrlich's The Axiom of Choice it may have the answer. Otherwise you could wait a couple of hours until I am near my copy again.

Comment: I don't want to disturb you, but that book is not in the library i'm studying. Would you mind posting a short summary?

Comment: Are you assuming $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R$ or a general metric space?

Comment: I referred $X$ to a subspace of Dedekind-infinite metric space

Comment: I think some constraints on $X$ will make it possible to prove.. The constraint should make there doesn't exist such JDH's space in the space, but i dunno which constraint can it be.

Comment: Thank you. It's off the topic, but do you simply reject unprovable statements in ZF?, since you are the only intuitionist i know. I'm kinda confused when i face this kind of problem..

Comment: I am not an intuitionist at all. My research is about the axiom of choice, but my meta-theory is usually ZFC (+large cardinals when needed).