# On separable metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the proof for the following a valid proof? This proof has a different approach from [others](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83876/589078).

**A metric space in which every infinite set has a limit point is separable.**

**Proof** Let $E$ be a countably infinite subset of $X$ and $y$ be a limit point of $E$. $N_{\epsilon}(y)$ contains a point $p \in E$ $\forall \hspace{2pt} \epsilon > 0$. For any $x \in X$, let $d(x,y)=\delta$. Then $p \in N_{\delta+\epsilon}(x)$ which implies $x$ is also a limit point. So every point of $X$ is either a limit point of E or a point of E or both and hence E is a countable dense subset making X separable.

Comment: I don't see how you conclude that $x$ is a limit point of E.  $\delta$ is fixed, so $\epsilon+\delta$ is not arbitrarily small.

Comment: Okay, I realized the mistake, thanks @saulspatz

Comment: My edit was for a typo. The last word, "seperable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the first and last sentences of your proof, it can't possibly be correct:

> Let $E$ be a countably infinite subset of $X$. ...hence $E$ is a countable dense subset.

If this is correct, you've proven that every countable subset of a topological space with your property is dense. But notice that the set $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$ has your property, but not every countable subset of it is dense.

The mistake is when you conclude that $x$ is a limit point. Now, it's not obvious to me why you say this (you just kind of say it with no proof), but it isn't true. For example, $y=1$ is a limit point of $E=(0, 1)$, but $x=1,000,000,000,000$ is not a limit point of $E$.

Comment: The space $[0,1]$, which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R\cup \{\pm\infty\},$ is perhaps a more prosaic example.  In the comments to the Q, the O.P. acknowledges that he erroneously assumed that $\delta$ could be arbitrary, for a fixed $x.$......+1

Comment: My edit was for the last word "susbet" of the 2nd line. Unlike my usual typo "sunset".