# Proving metric space consisting of infinite set with limit point is separable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, separable-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space such that every infinite set in it has a limit point. Prove that $X$ is separable

I've tried this question in following way:

Let $\{X_{1i},X_{2i},X_{3i}.....X_{ni}\}$ be infinite sets which has a limit point $\{x_1,x_2,x_3....x_n\}$ respectively. Since all above sequence has a limit point defined and contained in it, therefore we  can call these sequence as closed sets $\{X_{11},X_{12},...,x_1\}, \{X_{21},X_{22},...,x_2\}......,\{X_{n1},X_{n2},....,x_n\}.$ Hence union of all these closed set is closed & closed set implies that it is compact. We know that compact metric space is separable. Therefore at end $X$ is separable.

Is my way of proof legitimate enough?

Comment: A metric space $X$ is compact if and only if for every infinite subset $S \subset X$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $x$ is a limit point of $S$ (meaning every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point in $S$ other than itself).

Answer (score 2):

No, if $x_1$ is a limit point of $\{X_{1i}, X_{2i},\ldots\}$ it doesn't mean that $\{x_i, X_{1i}, X_{2i},\ldots\}$ is closed because for that we need *all* limit points to be in the set, not just the one.

It **is** however true that $X$ is compact if we know it's a metric space such that every infinite set has a limit point. But the proof for that goes along quite different lines. Several proofs of direct separability too can be found in the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83876/4280). Take a look.